# pill bugs in raised beds

Tags: bugs

I read the answers regarding pillbug in the garden. I realized I had a raised bed and no composting material. I placed the shallow bowl with beer in it. Before I could complete the project. ( I ran out of bowls and went back in the house) The pill bugs had drown in the bowls with beer.
I added more bowls and more beer. They are running to the smell of fermentation and drowning.
I think I will turn one bed  into a compost bed and see if that takes care of the pill bugs ringing the new spouting plants.
Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question; it's a thank you to an answer on a different question. Please see the [tour], [ask] and the [help] for more information.

Comment: You beat me to it.

Comment: This is most certainly on topic, guys.  This user19955 just needs a bit of guidance in wording his question.  Pill bugs...give them housing and food and they will come.  Take away the housing and food and they will diminish.  Pill bugs are not a gardener's worry.  I've never seen pill bugs dashing for a beer filled swimming pool!  That many IS a problem that obviously can be solved with a little elbow grease!

Comment: I'd like to chat with this OP!

Comment: @stormy, feel free to invite this OP into our regular chat room, or create a room for the two of you. That could help with the question and learning how to use the site. He/She still has a few days to edit it before it gets fully closed. I like that you want to reach out!